# Can animated dead have weapons and armour?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, necromancy

If I have put the time into creating some skeletons or zombies using the spell Animate Dead. Kept them active expending 3rd level spell slots can I equip them with items, like armour and weapons?

Also if I equip a weapon they don't normally use do they get disadvantage?

(Hoping for a zombie with splint and a Great axe :D)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reference Skeletons:

**Yes they can equip weapons and armor.**

**The do not inherently have disadvantage with any weapons or armor.**

Source: Monster Manual pg. 272

> **Animated Dead.** Whatever sinister force awakens a
>   skeleton infuses its bones with a dark vitality, adhering
>   joint to joint and reassembling dismantled limbs. This
>   energy motivates a skeleton to move and think in a
>   rudimentary fashion, though only as a pale imitation of
>   the way it behaved in life. An animated skeleton retains
>   no connection to its past, although resurrecting a
>   skeleton restores it body and soul, banishing the hateful
>   undead spirit that empowers it.
>   While most skeletons are the animated remains of
>   dead humans and other humanoids, skeletal undead can
>   be created from the bones of other creatures besides
>   humanoids, giving rise to a host of terrifying and
>   unique forms.

Portion that applies directly to the question, emphasis on important bits is my own:

> **Obedient Servants.** Skeletons raised by spell
>   are bound to the will of their creator. They follow
>   orders to the letter, never questioning the tasks their
>   masters give them, regardless of the consequences.
>   Because of their literal interpretation of commands
>   and unwavering obedience, skeletons adapt poorly to
>   changing circumstances. They can't read, speak, emote,
>   or communicate in any way except to nod, shake their
>   heads, or point. Still, skeletons are able to accomplish a
>   variety of relatively complex tasks.
>   **A skeleton can fight with weapons and wear armor**,
>   can load and fire a catapult or ttebuchet, scale a siege
>   ladder, form a shield wall, or dump boiling oil. **However,
>   it must receive careful instructions explaining how such
>   tasks are accomplished.**
>   Although they lack the intellect they possessed in
>   life, skeletons aren't mindless. Rather than break its
>   limbs attempting to batter its way through an iron
>   door, a skeleton tries the handle first. If that doesn't
>   work, it searches for another way through or around
>   the obstacle.

Reference Zombies:

**Yes, there is a direct reference to weapons. No, they are not at disadvantage.**

Source: Monster Manual pg. 315, under the *Mindless Soldiers* paragraph.

> A zombie armed
>   with a weapon uses it, but the zombie won't retrieve a
>   dropped weapon or other tool until told to do so.